# HTML "this" versus AngularJS ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs

We are in the process of converting a very old ColdFusion application that made convenient use of "this" in conjunction with a function that did formatting:

```
<td>$<input type="text" name="txtTaxProration" id="txtTaxProration" value="0.00" alt="Tax Proration" onblur="dollarBlur(this);"></td>
```

The dollarBlur function would convert the numeric input to currency, i.e if the user entered 123, it was converted to 123.00; 23.45 was left as 23.45. This made the reference on the HTML side easy, but even easier in the actual function as the name of the element did not have to be specified. Is there some analogous way to do this in Angular?

```
<td>$<input type="text" ng-model="NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty" name="txtHomeWarrantyPolicy" id="txtHomeWarrantyPolicy" value="0.00" ng-change="angularDollarBlur(this)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"></td>
```

The following works fine, almost, HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty" ng-change="reCalcX('NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty')" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ></td>
```

Controller

```
$scope.reCalcX = function (propName) {
           alert($scope.$eval(propName));
           $scope['propName'] = 666;
       };
```

$scope.$eval(propName) does correctly reflect what was entered on the webpage ($scope['propName'] is undefined). However, $scope['propName'] doesn't appear to work - the change is not reflected back in the webpage.

Comment: Need to understand that `ng` attributes are not using the global window scope but rather whatever angular scope is applicable to that part of the view.

Thus `this` in the view will be a controller or directive object.

Comment: charlietfl, not sure what you are saying...I was just comparing two different constructs. I was hoping to do something similar in the AngularJS world, that the DOM-world was doing with the "this" object.

Comment: you are comparing apples to oranges

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply pass the model.

```
ng-change="angularDollarBlur(NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty)"
```

```js
$scope.angularDollarBlur = function (model) {
    console.log(model);
}
```

Here's another example:

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.NetSheetDetail = {
    TxtHomeWarranty: 'Hello World!'
  };
  
  $scope.angularDollarBlur = function (text, obj, prop) {
    alert(text);
    obj[prop] = 'Nope.';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty" ng-change="angularDollarBlur(NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty,NetSheetDetail,'TxtHomeWarranty')" />
</div>
```

Comment: On the function side, won't you have to specify NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty? I don't want to have to do that, as the function will be used for other models, and I was hoping to reduce the amount of code like "this" allows in the non-Angular world.

Comment: No, you can name the parameter whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I can only make this work with the function as follows:
    
    $scope.myTest = function (dataIn) {
  $scope.NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty = utilsService.currency(dataIn)
};
As the function will be used with several models, how will it know which models to update w/o more information being oassed into the function? The following is the corresponding HTML:
    
    <td>$<input type="text" ng-model="NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty" value="0.00" alt="Home Warranty Policy" ng-change="myTest(NetSheetDetail.TxtHomeWarranty)" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"></td>

Comment: Added an example, look to console to see. note that if you need even more information, pass it in as additional arguments to the function.

Comment: That does not work as I want. I am trying to change the scope property in the function. I edited my original post with new HTML/code snippets that might better reflect what I am trying to do. The key is that the function should not need to explicitly know the scope property.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrapped teh propname in quotes, rather than just accessing it as in my example..

Comment: @stephen Updated with another example.